Как это исправить? Bat файл не закрывает сам себя
Я написал программу start.bat. Ничего необычного, она просто командой "start" запускает все нужные ярлыки:
Код:
@echo off
chcp 65001>nul
cd C:\Users\Павел\Desktop
start "" "Visual Studio Code"
start "" "Programming_projects"
start "" "compilation"
start "" "openexe"
exit

Но при запуске она ведёт себя странно: хоть она и открывает все нужные мне программы, но она не закрывает себя и несмотря на @echo off выводит следующее:

Мне нужно, чтобы она просто открывала программы, прописанные в командах "start", при автозапуске. Мало того, что консоль остаётся открытой, в ней ещё и логи какие-то.
Местоположение программы:
C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Как это исправить?
Если кому-то это надо, то вот мой рабочий стол:


Добавьте в конце exit и bat-файл будет закрываться.

exit у меня есть. @echo off
chcp 65001>nul
cd C:\Users\Павел\Desktop
start "" "Visual Studio Code"
start "" "Programming_projects"
start "" "compilation"
start "" "openexe"
exit

По одной проги тестил запускать?Если одну написать и потом exit результат такойже? или пройдет.

У меня главное этот .bat файл когда запускаешь просто так, то консоль закрывается. А когда выключаешь и включаешь компьютер, то консоль не закрывается. А когда закрываешь консоль вручную, то пропадает VS Code, а все остальные программы, запущенные файлом start.bat, остаются открытыми. Я не знаю, как с этим бороться.

Мне кажется, причина в другом. Только сейчас обнаружил, что когда VS Code уже открыт, то консоль исчезает. А когда VS Code закрыт, то остаётся. И записывает те самые логи в консоль. exit стоит в конце, но консоль не закрывается

Касаемо тестирования программ. Только при запуске VS Code появляется эта грёбаная консоль(тестировал без выключения компьютера). При запуске остальных она исчезает.

Нужно запускать VS Code, перенаправляя её потоки в/в в nul:, тогда она не прицепится к вашим stdin/stdout и не будет удерживать вашу консоль.
start "" "Visual Studio Code" >nul: <nul: 2>&1

